# Drag and Drop Items to a List ? (one sided way)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am building a page with items on a panel which you can drop into a list.

- Items I want to drop have to be different item when dropped into the list (not just different CSS).
- Items on the *right* list can be reordered (**I covered that part** with a [jquery plugin](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/))
- Items on the *left* panel CANNOT be reordered.
- I'd like to be able to get an plain array (or json) of the updated order of the (sortable) list so I can use it with Angular later.

How can I do this ?

[image]

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/10kfrj0h/

HTML

```
    <div class="left-panel">
        <h3>left Panel</h3>
        <div class="item-button">Table</div>
        <div class="item-button">Car</div>
        <div class="item-button">Tree</div>
        <div class="item-button">Star</div>
        <div class="item-button">Apple</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-container sortable list">
        <div class="list-item tree">Tree
            <button type="button">delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class="list-item car">Car
            <button type="button">delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class="list-item apple">Apple
            <button type="button">delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class="list-item star">Star
            <button type="button">delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class="list-item table">Table
            <button type="button">delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$('.sortable').sortable();
```